# Covering Edges in DAG

Tags: graph-theory, directed-graphs

On my textbook a covering edge is defined as:

> if a and b are distinct vertices of a digraph, then a is said to cover
> b if there is an edge from a to b and every path from a to b traverses
> this edge. If a covers b, the edge from a to b is called a covering
> edge.

And I'm working on the problem to prove:

> If there is a path in DAG D from a vertex, u, to vertex, v, then there is
> a path from u to v that only traverses covering edges

I think and I looked up online, DAG should only require no directed cycle (as opposed to cycle), so if we have something like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dkOIo.png) with a->b->d, a->c->d, then wouldn't a to d doesn't have covering edges?

Thank you.

(Problem source: [problem 2](https://dspace.mit.edu/bitstream/handle/1721.1/104426/6-042j-spring-2010/contents/exams/MIT6_042JS10_quiz03_sol.pdf))

Comment: The theorem doesn't only refer to the covering edges between a and d, but also the covering edge between other nodes, in this case  $c \rightarrow d$, $a\rightarrow c$.

Comment: Does that make the proof from your link clear?